# ag-grid: setting grid option 'suppressHorizontalScroll' after creation has no effect

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

How do I apply suppressHorizontalScroll (or any grid property I guess) after grid creation?

I'm trying to apply a grid footer using [aligned grids](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-aligned-grids/exampleAlignedFloatingFooter.html) on an already created grid but it seems like setting `suppressHorizontalScroll` on the main grid doesn't have any effect. Still seeing the horizontal scrollbar.

If it matters, the grid itself is created via the angular 1 directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of the properties that you provide to the ag-grid are checked once on initializing the grid. You could change the value as you have done, then re-initialize the grid. Or you could just set the `overflow-x` to `'hidden'` on the `ag-body-viewport` class (unless you have multiple grids, there will only be one div element with this class)

Comment: Thanks. I guess most of the grid option properties are read once at init. If I understand the design philosophy correctly: options that are considered dynamic are watched using callbacks (eg scroll lag).